# How to modify existing major-mode?

Tags: major-mode, bibtex

I've made a minor change to the existing code in `bibtex.el`; to be more precise, I've modified the function `bibtex-generate-url-list` so that it can generate URLs for several more fields (in addition to the DOI and URL fields that the existing code can handle).

I have written the code that I need, that's not a problem. The problem is that I don't know how to make emacs see the changes.

What I tried:

1. Back up the original files `bibtex.el.gz` and the byte-compiled version `bibtex.elc`.
2. Save my changes in the old location and byte-compile the file. So the versions of `bibtex.el.gz` and `bibtex.elc` in the directory `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/textmodes` now contain my changes.
3. Restart emacs.

But my changes don't seem to work when I load a bibtex file.

So how can I make emacs use my changes?

---

For completeness, here is the code I added (everything after the doi entry). I've tested the regular expressions and they do what I want, so that's not the issue, as I explained above.

```
(defcustom bibtex-generate-url-list
 '((("url" . ".*:.*"))
(("doi" . "10\\.[0-9]+/.+")
 "http://dx.doi.org/%s"
 ("doi" ".*" 0))
(("mrkey" . "\\(mr\\)?[0-9]\\{1,8\\}")
 "http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=%s"
 ("mrkey" "\\(mr\\)?\\([0-9]\\{1,8\\}\\)" 2))
(("arxiv" . "\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\.[0-9]\\{4,5\\}\\|[-a-z]+/[0-9]\\{7\\}\\|[-a-z]+\\.[a-z]\\{2\\}/[0-9]\\{7\\}\\)\\(v[0-9]+\\)?")
 "http://arxiv.org/abs/%s"
 ("arxiv" ".*" 0))
(("zblnumber" . "\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\.[0-9]\\{5\\}\\|[0-9]\\{8\\}\\)")
 "http://zbmath.org/?q=an:%s"
 ("zblnumber" ".*" 0)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Never modify the source code in its original location like that. You'll lose (or be forced to merge) your changes whenever you upgrade.
2. `defcustom` defines a "user option" variable. Variables are designed to be modified without touching the code, and for user options there's even a UI for that:

   <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `bibtex-generate-url-list` <kbd>RET</kbd>

   Emacs will save your customisations into your init file (or your `custom-file`, should that value be set).

   Type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to visit the manual, and then <kbd>m</kbd> `Customization` <kbd>RET</kbd> to read about this facility.
3. If you ever do find yourself needing to redefine some existing code, you can achieve that in your personal init file, without editing the original code.
4. To set a user option value in code in your init file, use `customize-set-variable`:

   ```el
   (customize-set-variable
    'bibtex-generate-url-list
    '((("url" . ".*:.*"))
      (("doi" . "10\\.[0-9]+/.+")
       "http://dx.doi.org/%s"
       ("doi" ".*" 0))
      (("mrkey" . "\\(mr\\)?[0-9]\\{1,8\\}")
       "http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=%s"
       ("mrkey" "\\(mr\\)?\\([0-9]\\{1,8\\}\\)" 2))
      (("arxiv" . "\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\.[0-9]\\{4,5\\}\\|[-a-z]+/[0-9]\\{7\\}\\|[-a-z]+\\.[a-z]\\{2\\}/[0-9]\\{7\\}\\)\\(v[0-9]+\\)?")
       "http://arxiv.org/abs/%s"
       ("arxiv" ".*" 0))
      (("zblnumber" . "\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\.[0-9]\\{5\\}\\|[0-9]\\{8\\}\\)")
       "http://zbmath.org/?q=an:%s"
       ("zblnumber" ".*" 0))))
   ```

   You might also set it with `setq` (or just `set`, for a direct substitution in the above code), and with the majority of variables it won't matter, but there *are* some user options for which you need to be using `customize-set-variable`, so it's best to use that.

   If the variable was defined by `defvar` then you can safely use `setq`/`set` to set its value.

Comment: Is there some way to customize it by adding code to my init file rather than using the customization interface?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Minor point: shouldn't it be `custom-set-variables`? At least, I put the code in `custom-set-variables` in my init file and that worked.

Comment: Using your `custom-set-variables` form will work fine, yes, and that was what my answer originally used. I changed it to `customize-set-variable` partly because it reduces the level of nesting in the code, but mostly because the init file comments suggest there should only be one call to `custom-set-variables`, so I didn't want to recommend that people add new ones (not that I know why that warning appears).